# Corners of NSView are transparent but shouldn't be

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSView` called `myNSView` in a `NSPopover`. I added to the `myNSView` a corner radius of 15. But my problem is that the edges get transparent (see image). Behind `myNSView` is a further `NSView` which contains a red background color. I don't know why the edges don't get red. Any advice?

```
self.myNSView.wantsLayer = true
self.myNSView.layer?.cornerRadius = 15
self.myNSView.layer?.backgroundColor = Colors.white()
```

[image: NSView]

Comment: To clarify, the grey edges should be red?

Comment: Yes, the grey edges should be red!

Comment: You have to set your views window background to red

Comment: Set background color of NSPopover as red color, I hope this may fix your need

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

[image]

If that's the case, you can make the `BackgroundView` and `myNSView` as subclasses of NSView and overwrite the colors there like I did [here](https://github.com/johnisaac/PopoverStackOverflow)?

Comment: Yes thats what I like to do. I tried your code and it worked but it only works when I haven't inserted a other view in myNSView. As soon as I insert a view (like a NSTextField or a NSImageView) ind myNSView, the corners get transparent.

Comment: Hmmm...that shouldn't happen because even in my code, both BackgroundView and MyNSView have a label field inside them

Comment: are you adding `NSTextField` in code or Interface Builder?

Comment: Hmmm. may be an auto layout issue or you are using `StackView` ? sure, Xcode is not throwing errors in the console